# NULL в условии Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Этот селект не работает потому что есть NULL в условии.

```
SELECT A.COL1 AS A_COL1,
       B.COL1 AS B_COL1,
       A.COL2 AS A_COL2,
       B.COL2 AS B_COL2
     FROM ( SELECT 
                NULL  COL1,
                2 COL2
                FROM  DUAL ) A INNER JOIN ( SELECT 
        NULL COL1,
        2 COL2
        FROM DUAL 
        ) B ON  A.COL1 = B.COL1  AND A.COL2  = B.COL2;
```

Добавляю функию NVL, исключаю NULL в работает.  Правильно считатет.

```
SELECT A.COL1 AS A_COL1,
       B.COL1 AS B_COL1,
       A.COL2 AS A_COL2,
       B.COL2 AS B_COL2
     FROM ( SELECT 
                NULL COL1,
                2 COL2
                FROM  DUAL ) A INNER JOIN ( SELECT 
        NULL COL1,
        2 COL2
        FROM DUAL 
        ) B ON  NVL(TO_CHAR(A.COL1),'0') = NVL(TO_CHAR(B.COL1),'0')  AND NVL(TO_CHAR(A.COL2),'0') = NVL(TO_CHAR(B.COL2),'0');
```

Этот селект работает с функцией и без считает правильно. Но без фунции я не исключаю сравнение с  NULL. Как же правильно. ?

```
SELECT  CC.CODUL, SUM(A.COL1) AS COL1
   FROM ( SELECT 'A0111' CAEM2, 1 COL1
          FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
          SELECT 'A0112' CAEM2, 1 COL1
          FROM DUAL
          UNION  ALL
        SELECT    NULL CAEM2,  1 COL1 FROM DUAL   
            )  A INNER JOIN (SELECT  
'00000'   CODUL,'00000'  GRUPA,'00000;'  FULL_CODE
FROM DUAL  UNION ALL SELECT  
'A0000'  CODUL, '00000' GRUPA, '00000;A0000;'  FULL_CODE FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT   'A0100' CODUL, 'A0000'   GRUPA, '00000;A0000;A0100;'  FULL_CODE FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL  SELECT  'A0110'   CODUL, 'A0100'   GRUPA, '00000;A0000;A0100;A0110;'  FULL_CODE FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT   'A0111'   CODUL, 'A0110'   GRUPA, '00000;A0000;A0100;A0110;A0111;'  FULL_CODE FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL  SELECT   'A0112'   CODUL, 'A0110'   GRUPA,'00000;A0000;A0100;A0110;A0112;'  FULL_CODE
 FROM DUAL) C ON (C.CODUL = NVL(TO_CHAR(A.CAEM2),'0'))
 INNER JOIN (
SELECT  '00000'   CODUL,'00000'   GRUPA,'00000;'  FULL_CODE FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT  'A0000'         CODUL,'00000' GRUPA,'00000;A0000;'  FULL_CODE
 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
 SELECT  
'A0100'   CODUL,'A0000'   GRUPA,'00000;A0000;A0100;'  FULL_CODE
 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
 SELECT  
'A0110'   CODUL,'A0100'   GRUPA, '00000;A0000;A0100;A0110;'  FULL_CODE
 FROM DUAL  UNION ALL  SELECT  
'A0111'   CODUL, 'A0110'   GRUPA, '00000;A0000;A0100;A0110;A0111;'  FULL_CODE
FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
 SELECT   'A0112'   CODUL, 'A0110'   GRUPA, '00000;A0000;A0100;A0110;A0112;'  FULL_CODE
 FROM DUAL

     ) CC ON (C.FULL_CODE LIKE '%'||CC.CODUL||';%')

 GROUP BY 
 CC.CODUL,
 CC.FULL_CODE

 ORDER BY 
 CC.FULL_CODE
```

Как правильно  логически ?   С функции или без ?
  С функцией он исключат все  UNKNOWN .
 Есть еще Объяснения.

Comment: А вы можете более точно сформулировать вопрос?, а то я не понял, что вы не поняли)

Comment: сравнения там у него `null = null`

Comment: @Viktorov Вообще говоря, сравнение с `NULL` возвращает `UNKNOWN` (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm), иначе `not (column = null)` возвращало бы `true`. Для практических целей лучше запомнить это в виде "сравнение с `NULL` никогда не возвращает `true`".

Comment: Сравсненеие с NULL возварщает  UNKNOWN

Comment: Логически правильно так, что бы результат был такой, как требуется. В случае если и в одной и в другой выборке есть NULL они считались равными 0 и соответственно сравнивались между собой - то надо использовать nvl или отдельно добавить условия на IS NULL. А если такие строки в результате не нужны, то можно оставить как есть (без nvl)

Comment: нужны все строки и с  NULL  и без NULL.

Comment: может есть другое объяснение  ?

Comment: Какая исходная задача? Как-то меня напрягают джойны с dual. Чего Вы хотите добиться?

Answer (score 0):

NULL означает "нет значения", оно не может быть равно или не равно. Соответственно, в твоем третьем куске кода первое соединение `C.CODUL = NVL(TO_CHAR(A.CAEM2),'0')` возьмет только 1 и 2 строчку из таблицы А, равносильно как и `C.CODUL = A.CAEM2` возьмет эти же строчки из таблицы А. Почему? Потому что функция NVL подставляет вместо всех значений NULL значение "по умолчанию" '0' (в твоем случае), а в таблице C у столбца C.CODUL нет значения '0', т.е. ты передал заведомо ложное значение, если бы ты использовал, скажем, `C.CODUL = NVL(TO_CHAR(A.CAEM2),'00000')`, то результат был бы совсем не такой, как при выборке по условию `C.CODUL = NVL(TO_CHAR(A.CAEM2),'0')` или `C.CODUL = A.CAEM2`.

Comment: Смысл моего добавления этой функции, я хочу избежать сравнениея с NULL.
Хотя и с функциий и без считате правильно. Но я хочу  избажать сравнение с  NULL.

Comment: С NULL и так ничего не сравнивается никогда, значение NULL не определено, оно не может быть чему-то равным или не равным. В NVL обертывают аргумент, если хотят использовать вместо NULL какое-то значение "по умолчанию",  которое может быть в столбце второй таблицы, если передавать по умолчанию что-то, чего нет и не будет во второй таблице - в этом нет особого смысла.